# Making phpunit ignore include?

Tags: php, phpunit, travis-ci

I have a file with a single include like this one:

**file.php**

```php
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/anotherfile.php");
class file {
    function myfunction() {
        $class = new anotherfile();
        $class->functionfromanotherfile();
    }
    function myfunctionToBeTested() {
        // do things here
    }
}
```

I'm using travis-ci to run my tests with phpunit, and the problem is that I dont commit the "anotherfile.php" (have the logic and credentials to connect to the database), which makes it not work when I try to include this file in my test script.

**tests.php**

```php
class tests extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function test_function() {
        include(dirname(__FILE__)."/file.php");
        $class = new file();
    }
}
```

I could make another file with only the function I need to test and go with it but maybe you guys can come up with other awnser.

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of [dependency injection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection):

- Modify the class you want to test so that it accepts the credentials as parameters of the constructor.
- In the test, create fake -or real- credentials and pass them to the constructor of your class.